# Object property is treated as null after setting with Number() even though it logs as having value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running into a strange issue where I cannot access a field of an object I have defined unless I explicitly set that field to a number value.

I am trying to access the field with the following

```
if (userCache[mem.id][action.field]) {
```

this if block is not being entered. I am console.log()'ing the above value before this conditional, and it shows the value as 0, which is what it was previously set to using:

```
if (!isNaN(action.fieldvalue)) {
    valToSet = Number(action.fieldvalue);
} else {
    valToSet = action.fieldvalue;
}
userCache[mem.id][action.field] = valToSet;
```

Where action.fieldvalue is the value I want to set, but it's a string. If I instead set the value using = 0 , instead of = Number(), then I am able to access it correctly in the conditional.

Comment: Seems unlikely that setting it using `= 0` would enter the if block. Something else might be changing it. `0` is falsy and `if (0)` will not run, so it not running when the value is logged as 0 is expected.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you understand the scenario:

```
$ node
> const a = '0';
> const b = Number('0');
> if (a) { console.log("true") } else { console.log("false") }
> if (b) { console.log("true") } else { console.log("false") }
```

To clarify, "0" string is not a falsy value since its not empty but 0 number is.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to Js so I forgot that if (0) returns false.